# How can a CodeIgniter controller accept an ajax post

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I have a (CodeIgniter) VIEW that includes this...

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
...
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "controller/preview_offer",
        data: jsonString, 
        cache: false,

        success: function(){
            alert("OK");
        }
    });        
...
</script>
```

Problem is that when I run it, I keep getting the "OK" alert, and absolutely nothing else.

My controller has a simple popup where I am hoping to find the jsonString coming through, but nothing happens at all.

My URL is formed just like I would use in a normal `anchor()` function, and I've tested it by putting in the explicit URL `http://mydomain/index.php/controller/preview_offer` - and it works.

I get the feeling that I've got an error here more fundamental than just syntax. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your controller/preview_offer doing? What http code does it return? What are you expecting to get? You hit the page successfully, the success callback runs and you get an "OK" alert. Change your success function to function(data) and then console.log(data); inside of it. Hit control+shift+i and switch to console to see what's being sent back.

Comment: the preview_offer is a script to generate a pdf. I'm trying to get the array via ajax to this script, so that the PDF can be generated.

Comment: You likely have the data you sent. Within php `var_dump($_POST['data']);`

Comment: In my console I am getting masses of HTML... styling, raw HTML, the whole lot. But still nothing in my preview_offer function.

Comment: Did you choose the console tab of the console? Before that ajax call `console.log("++++++++", jsonString);` and then see if it appears in the console with the correct data. (and post that object here. Use: `console.log("++++++++", JSON.stringify(jsonString));` to create a copy/pasteable string representation.)

Comment: {"length":0} 61:129
++++++++ {"glossary":{"title":"example glossary","GlossDiv":{"title":"S","GlossList":{"GlossEntry":{"ID":"SGML","SortAs":"SGML","GlossTerm":"Standard Generalized Markup Language","Acronym":"SGML","Abbrev":"ISO 8879:1986","GlossDef":{"para":"A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.","GlossSeeAlso":["GML","XML"]},"GlossSee":"markup"}}}}} 61:157
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

Comment: <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: data</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/controller.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 205</p>

</div><pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
</pre>

Comment: You get that PHP notice when the ajax call runs or when you hit it directly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57726/discussion-between-maxcot-and-mkaatman).

Comment: have you tried the url with a trailing slash. was my problem once

Answer (score 1):

You should change your success function to something like this:

```
success: function(data){
        alert("OK");
        $( "#results" ).append( data );
    }
```

And also for setting a controller URL in view use: `site_url("controller/preview_offer");`

Answer (score 0):

your code will not run because of the url..try to change it a make it like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: <?php echo site_url("controller/preview_offer");?>,
    data: jsonString, 
    cache: false,

    success: function(){
        alert("OK");
    }
});
```